# How can I remove a specific part of many folders names using .bat files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation

My university is using a proprietary system that outputs data in a very specific way in which each "module" is output into folders following the structure (4 digit numeral) - (name of module)

ex: 5574-CHEM104

I need to remove the name and hyphen so that only the numeral remains:
5574-CHEM104 > 5574

The problem is that there's thousands of these folders and there's no way I could do it by hand. I'm having difficulty trying to automate the process, so if anyone could at least point out a command I could look into it would help immensely

I've tried the REN command, putting "REN 5574-CHEM104 5574", but it only works for one folder. There's thousands of folders, each with different numerals, under "CHEM104", for example, and I need for the program to rename the folder no matter the original name into the first 4 original numerals, which I can't figure out. Thanks!

Comment: If the numeric part always consists of four figures, use `ren "????-*" "????"`; otherwise, use `for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=-" %%I in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S "*-*"') do ren "%%I-%%J" "%%I"`…

Comment: Note: if there is even a remote possibility that the character following the first hyphen can be a space character, please do not use the example above, (or the current answer). The renamed directory beginning with a space character will likely cause you major problems moving forward.

Comment: Does it have to be batch, or would Powershell work just as well?

Comment: powershell would work just as well, do you have some suggestions on that front?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO FOR /f "delims=-" %%o IN ("%%e") DO ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%e" "%%o"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the directories.

Using a list of the directory-names, names only (`/b`) and directories only (`/ad`), tokenise the name using `-` as a delimiter and execute the `rename` using the token assigned to `%%o` (default is first token)